# VB.Net Windows from App Consume Web Service, Curl Equivalant

Tags: vb.net, web-services, curl, soap

I'm trying to consume a web service from my windows form app.  If I use curl it works fine but from my windows for app it just gets an error,

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

I think its due to certificates, and I'm not sure how to replicate what I've done using curl in VB, below is my curl script.

```
curl -i -v --cert certname.crt:psw --key mykey.key --data-binary "@avcheck.xml" -H "Content-Type:text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"" https://here.there.com/websrv
```

can any one tell me how to replicate this in my windows from app?

Thanks